What is known about the 5th century church discovered in Nevsehir?
I have been trying to find any additional information on the news that were published in 2016 about underground church discovered in Turkey, Nevsehir. But there is nothing. Can anyone help?
Here is one of the news: https://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/historic-church-discovered-in-turkeys-nevsehir-could-change-history-of-orthodoxy-94309
Here is a photo of one of the frescos from the news. 

Here are some additional articles I could find

2016-2018 article

The excavation at an area of 396,000 m2 (4,262,508 square feet) that started 4 years ago is to be opened for visitors at an area of 100,000 m2 (1,076,391 square feet) by July 2018. Along with the well-preserved cave church, dated back to the 6th century, found during the excavations, there was also found a cave mosque dated back to the Great Seljuk Turks since reusing was also pretty common in Anatolia. From Ottoman Era (Damat Ibrahim Pasha) to the first few years of the Republic; a total of 80,000 documents were studied to find out more details and thanks to the information studied on these sources that, there was also an aqueduct commissioned by the Fatma Sultan, the wife of Damat Ibrahim Pasha.


2018 article

Semih İstanbulluoğlu, the archaeologist who heads the works for both the underground city and the church, explained that the walls of the church collapsed because of snow and rain, but that they will be fixed as part of the restoration project.
...
When uncovered, the church was filled with earth. Ali Aydin, another member of the archaeological team in charge of the Nevsehir discoveries, said that because of the humidity underground the church has to be dried slowly in order to prevent even more damage to the frescoes. “We have stopped work in order to protect the wall paintings and the church. When the weather gets warmer in the spring, we will wait for humidity to evaporate and then we will start removing the earth. Only a few of the paintings have been revealed. Others will emerge when the earth is removed.


2024 article

The church in Nevşehir has not been officially named yet. It is currently being referred to as the “Nevşehir Underground Church” or the “Church of the Ascension” due to the prominent fresco depicting Jesus’ ascension into heaven. The archaeologists who discovered the church are still working to piece together its history and identify its exact origins.




This all is very strange. Looks like they are hiding something. This is sensation(!) Why is there so little information? And thanks for your searches

the 2018 article mentions they have to excavate slowly to humidity doesn't cause more damage. Sounds like a long process of working and waiting. Also it says it's open to visitors (part of it is) so I don't know about hiding things

okay I think you are probably right
